# How to get all users associated with a group and type using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I got a table with username, usergroup and usertype.

```
A 0 0
B 0 1
C 1 2
D 2 2
```

Now i want something like

> get all the users where the group is 0 or 1 and type is 2

I use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE usergroup= 0 OR 1 AND usertype=2 GROUP BY usergroup
```

I expect it will return the username `C`, but strangely it returns `A,C,D`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `usergroup= 0 OR 1` will presumably evaluate `usergroup= 0` as a boolean then interpret the `1` as the boolean `true`. Meaning your query is `WHERE usergroup= 0 OR (1 AND usertype=2)` =  `WHERE usergroup= 0 OR (true AND usertype=2)` =  `WHERE usergroup= 0 OR usertype=2`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Why is that a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - It only answers half the question ("What am I doing wrong?"). There were already answers giving the syntax to use. Actually I am doubting it as that would return all rows not just 3. (Edit. The four become three because of the `GROUP BY` of course!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I'm going to ignore that `GROUP BY`.</sub>

---

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table WHERE usergroup= 0 OR 1 AND usertype=2
> ```
>
> What am I doing wrong?

First, you have precedence issues; your SQL query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE usergroup = 0 OR (1 AND usertype=2)
```

Use parentheses to be clear:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (usergroup = 0 OR 1) AND usertype=2
```

There's still a problem, in that boolean operators simply don't work like this: `0 OR 1` is an expression that evaluates to `1`.

You have to repeat the thing you're comparing against:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (usergroup = 0 OR usergroup = 1) AND usertype=2
```

However, this can be shortened thus:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE usergroup IN (0, 1) AND usertype=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL should be :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (usergroup = 0 OR usergroup = 1) 
  AND (usertype = 2)
```

Why do you need a 'GROUP BY' is unclear, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE usergroup IN (0,1) AND usertype = 2
```

Comment: @user762683: Great! Do you understand _why_?

Comment: Yep, you (Tomalak Geret'kal) explained it pretty well. Thanks